# Not able to schedule tasks in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, vi

```
[srinkann@sjc-ads-440 ~]$ crontab -e
no crontab for srinkann - using an empty one
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/vi: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 127
[srinkann@sjc-ads-440 ~]$
```

In Google, i got the below solution, but no permission for me to do that.

```
ln -s /bin/vi /usr/bin/vi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you can use `vi`. There is a workaround:

```
crontab -l > crontab.txt
vi crontab.txt
crontab crontab.txt
```

You can make your modifications in the `crontab.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

execute on the command line AND put the following in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` or whatever is appropriate for your shell):

```sh
EDITOR='/bin/vi'
VISUAL='/bin/vi'
export EDITOR VISUAL
```

Depending on your shell, you might even be able to do something like this:

```sh
EDITOR=$(type -p vim || type -p vi || type -p nvi)
VISUAL="$EDITOR"
export EDITOR VISUAL
```